# html visual editing like whatsapp in php

Tags: php, html, markdown

recent version of whatsapp introduced little bit of styling the message, suppose we want to write something like this

`input` This is a ~statement~ which has styling in it

`output` This is a <strike>statement</strike> which has styling in it

even stackoverflow has this kind of minimal styling which gives great look, we want to implement this in our platform where teachers while giving remark to student can give ol, ul, bold, italic but we also want to make sure they are not allowed to use traditional html tags because when tag changes we have to make changes instead we like the approach where you can add special character with word and turn them way you want in the output.

I don't know what is the specific terms for this type of editing so please ignore it.

**language** since our platform is already running in `php` we would like to implement that in php

**thought process** we thought it might be possible with `regex` but don't know how to implement ol, ul and we are not very sure if that is a correct method to implement

**why not allowing traditional html tags**

1. Not all of them know traditional html tags
2. want to keep our application secure

Comment: Why don't you use a WYSIWYG like CKEditor?

Comment: Just do a search for Markdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this GitHub library](https://github.com/cebe/markdown)

Here are some examples:

```
// traditional markdown and parse full text
$parser = new \cebe\markdown\Markdown();
$parser->parse($markdown);

// use github markdown
$parser = new \cebe\markdown\GithubMarkdown();
$parser->parse($markdown);

// use markdown extra
$parser = new \cebe\markdown\MarkdownExtra();
$parser->parse($markdown);

// parse only inline elements (useful for one-line descriptions)
$parser = new \cebe\markdown\GithubMarkdown();
$parser->parseParagraph($markdown);
```

Comment: Where can I find the css for the syntax highlighting? For example the <code class='language-php'>.

Comment: The `<code />` element has some default styling. If you want to personalize this style, you can do so in your own css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions like this:

```
/~([\w]*)~/
```

With `preg_replace()` function you can replace the content between `~` symbols with all you need. For example:

https://regex101.com/r/vD8wI4/2

Note the substitution tab, where I replace `~text~`  with `<pre>text</pre>`.

The same technique applicable to bold, italic, etc:

Bold:

```
/\*([\w]*)\*/
```

Italic:

```
/_([\w]*)_/
```

Etc.

Good luck.